# How to open workbooks in a different excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a method `Do Folder(Folder)` which is for looping through sub folders and in this method for each file which matches the right criteria I want to edit the workbook. However when I get to the right folder error apear saying the file doesn't exist. Here is the code:

```
    Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If File.Type = "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet" Then

            Dim wb As Workbook
            Dim ws As Worksheet


            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File.Path, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Editable:=True)
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
            ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


        Else

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

And here is the problem magnified:

```
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File.Path, ReadOnly:=False,  IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Editable:=True)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

For whatever reason the debugger shows `wb` as Nothing and that's probably the problem but how do I fix it?

Comment: not sure, but I think you're opening the path, not the file, have you looked at file.path?  should it be file.path & "\" & file.name?

Comment: : Path : "C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\New folder\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm" : String

Comment: that is the value for file.path

Comment: am I trying to open the File the wrong way? or am i in the wrong layer?

Comment: Have you tried Dim File as scripting.file and simply opening without the extra arguments

Comment: i don't scripting.file is. what would it do?

Comment: for some reason however i get the error that i cant have two files open at the same time. how do i bypass that?

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works fine

Comment: yeah but for me i wont let me have two documents open at the same time. i dont know how that happened it worked fine befor

Comment: Excel won't allow you to open two files with the same name at the same time - is the workbook running the code in the same folder as the list of files you want to edit?  Could be it's trying to load the code file again.  Secondly, move the declarations of `wb` ans `ws` outside the loop; you don't need to declare them on every iteration...

Comment: Thanks! if you write a full and proper answer ill give you the check mark

Answer (score 0):

Include an additional window in the toolbar and in the debug mode, see the name of the file `View\Locals Window`. They may be temporary (the ones that are now open).  Name this file starting with `~$`.
Cuts temporary files, for example:

```
If Mid ([filename], 1, 2) <> "~$" Then
```